# Is there a way to decide template argument types of template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two template classes those's arguments are decided in different layers of the software.
The class that I have to use in lower layer is

```
template <class RoutineInfoId, 
         class ErrorInfoId, 
         class LoadBarInfoId>
class InformCBSet
```

The class that I have to use in upper layer is

```
template <class LanguageId,
          class RoutineInfoId, 
          class ErrorInfoId, 
          class LoadBarInfoId>
class Info
```

I can also create the 'Info' class

```
template <class LanguageId,
          class SomeInformCBSet>
```

whereas

```
typedef InformCBSet<SomeRoutineInfoId,
                    SomeErrorInfoId,
                    SomeLoadBarInfoId> SomeInformCBSet
```

I want to get  (that are the types of an lower layer class)from the SomeInfoCBSet in upper layer by using SomeInfoCBSet as template argument of 'Info class directly.

Any way to realize that?
Thanks

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question. Do you want to retrieve template arguments from a template specialization ? Like taking in `Foo<A, B, C>` and retrieving `A`, `B` and `C` ?

Comment: yes Quentin. exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another template as a helper to produce the desired type:

```
// Helper accepts two types: a language ID and an InformCBSet instantiation. This
// declares the base template, but we need to specialize it, so there is no base
// template implementation.
template <typename, typename>
struct InformCBSet_to_Info;

// Specialization where the second argument is an InformCBSet instantiation.
template <typename LanguageId,
          typename RoutineInfoId, 
          typename ErrorInfoId, 
          typename LoadBarInfoId>
struct InformCBSet_to_Info<LanguageId, InformCBSet<RoutineInfoId,
                                                   ErrorInfoId,
                                                   LoadBarInfoId>>
{
    typedef Info<LanguageId,
                 RoutineInfoId,
                 ErrorInfoId,
                 LoadBarInfoId> info_type;
};

typedef InformCBSet<SomeRoutineInfoId,
                    SomeErrorInfoId,
                    SomeLoadBarInfoId> SomeInformCBSet;

typedef InformCBSet_to_Info<SomeLanguageId, SomeInformCBSet>::info_type SomeInfoType;
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use this or something like it:

```
template<typename T> struct InformCBSetTypes;
template<typename T0, typename T1, typename T2>
struct InformCBSetTypes<InformCBSet<T0, T1, T2> > {
  typedef T0 RoutineInfoId;
  typedef T1 ErrorInfoId;
  typedef T2 LoadBarInfoId;
};
```

To be able to use `typename InformCBSetTypes<SomeInformCBSet>::RoutineInfoId` etc. in your `Info` class template. For purposes of demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T0, typename T1, typename T2>
struct InformCBSet { };

template<typename T> struct InformCBSetTypes;
template<typename T0, typename T1, typename T2>
struct InformCBSetTypes<InformCBSet<T0, T1, T2> > {
  typedef T0 RoutineInfoId;
  typedef T1 ErrorInfoId;
  typedef T2 LoadBarInfoId;
};

int main() {
  typedef InformCBSet<int, double, std::string> MySet;

  // Note: To use these inside a template, you'll have to write "typename"
  //       before them (as with all typedefs in dependent types) so that the
  //       compiler knows to expect a type before it knows which specialization
  //       of InformCBSetTypes it's ultimately going to use.
  InformCBSetTypes<MySet>::RoutineInfoId i = 1;                // int
  InformCBSetTypes<MySet>::ErrorInfoId   d = 2.3;              // double
  InformCBSetTypes<MySet>::LoadBarInfoId s = "Hello, world!";  // string

  std::cout << i << ", " << d << ", " << s << std::endl;
}
```